# Is it possible to access variable set by hooks inside callback function

Tags: javascript, redux, react-hooks

I am using hooks to set varibale as such:

```
const [test1, setTest1] = useState('')
const [test2, setTest2] = useState('')
```

The value of test 1 and test2 are set after userinput `onChnage={(e)=>setTest1(e.target.value)}` and `onChnage={(e)=>setTest2(e.target.value)}`

Now is it possible to access the value of test1 and test2 in callback function? I have function that gets called on form submit button click as below but I am getting test1 and test2 as undefined.

```
const onHandleSubmit = useCallback( (event) => {
    console.log(test1)
    console.log(test2)
    let data = {
       test1 : test1,
       test2 : test2
    }
    dispatch({type: 'send/data', data:data});
},[]);
```

Comment: form submit usually has all the data, `event.target.form.value`

Answer (score 3):

You need to write the variables used in the callback into the observations array as shown below:

```
const onHandleSubmit = useCallback( (event) => {
    console.log(test1)
    console.log(test2)
    let data = {
       test1,
       test2
    }
    dispatch({type: 'send/data', data:data});
},[test1, test2]); // <====
```